# Проблемы с форматом JSX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

Делаю по [вот этому руководству](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/25.1.php) первое свое приложение с React.

Проделываю точь в точь по шагам, но в итоге не работает и пишет следующую ошибку в консоли:

> app.jsx:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Перейдя по которой видим ошибку следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема?

Comment: а при запуске приложения работает нормально? у вас в ошибке упомянут app, а на скриншоте test.

Comment: это я поменял на test, после того как не заработало поменял на app, но скрин уже не перезаливал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю почему в указанном руковдстве не написано, но чуть-чуть погуглив, я понял что для конвертации из JSX в обычный JS нужен Babel.
Для решения моей проблемы добавил после скриптов, скрипт подключения Babel и на js файле указал тип=бабел

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/react/app.jsx")'></script>`

Answer (score -2):

убедитесь импортирован ли react, react-dom.
p.s. каждый файл содержащий JSX должен иметь доступ к React.
[image: работает :)]

Comment: Вы заблуждаетесь. Трансформом jsx в ванильку не реакт занимается, потому утверждение "каждый файл содержащий jsx должен иметь доступ к React" - неверно.